# How do you access a variable instead of re-declaring it? Or what is another alternative to doing this?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I fix these errors I get in JSBin?
JSBin 
http://jsbin.com/ebizaj/edit#javascript,html
I get these errors.

```
1.Line 6: var name = prompt("What is your name?", ""); --- 'name' is already defined.
2.Line 12: var PromptAnswer = prompt("So, " + name + " do you play Soccer?", ""); --- 'PromptAnswer' is already defined.
3.Line 35: var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", ""); --- 'PromptAnswer3' is already defined.
```

What should I do?  If I were to try to call the variable PromptAnswer3, it would do nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Javascript Activity</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function InitAll() 
{
var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
while (name == null | name == "") {
alert("You didn't answer! :D");
var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
}
alert("Hello, " + name + " this is a little Javascript Activity!");
var PromptAnswer = prompt("So, " + name + " do you play Soccer?", "");
while (PromptAnswer == null | PromptAnswer == "")  {
alert("You didn't answer, please try again.");
var PromptAnswer = prompt("So, " + name + " do you play Soccer?", "");
}

else if (PromptAnswer.match(/^(yes|yeah)!?$/i))
{
alert("Cool, that's awesome, i play Soccer too!");
var PromptAnswer2 = prompt("Well, even some people play Soccer and don't like it, do you like soccer?", "");
    if (PromptAnswer2.match(/^(yes|yeah)!?$/i)) 
    {
    alert("Yeah, its pretty fun.");
    }
else
{
    alert("Well, that's really too bad, but i guess if you don't like it, you dont like it. :D");
}
}


else {
var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    while (PromptAnswer3 == null | PromptAnswer3 == "") 
    {
    alert("You didn't answer");
    var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
    }
if (PromptAnswer3.match(/^(yes|yeah)!?$/i)) 
    {
    alert("Haha yeah, football is pretty awesome, even though i'm a Javascript Script, my Creator can throw football pretty well. :D");
    }
else
    {
        alert(PromptAnswer3 + " is pretty cool.");
    }
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="InitAll()">
<noscript>
<p>Sorry, you do not have Javascript Enabled for this Activity.</p>
</noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `var` before a variable name, you're declaring it. You can only declare a given variable once [within a scope](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html), and in each of the three error messages, you're doing `var [variable name]` more than once.

You can reuse your variables later, without putting `var` in front of them each time. So, on line 6 of your script, simply remove the `var` - it's repetitive, and not needed.

Remove the duplicate `var` on each line mentioned in the each of the error messages, and you're done.

Comment: Hmm, so all i do is just write 'var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
while (name === null | name === "") {
alert("You didn't answer! :D");
name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
}'

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a variable before assigning a value to it. For example, instead of writing

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
while (name === null | name === "") {
    alert("You didn't answer! :D");
    var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
}
```

you can write

```
var name;
name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
while (name === null | name === "") {
    alert("You didn't answer! :D");
    name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Hehe i didnt understand that XD, i'm sorta new to JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm, it seems i get errors while having a While and an if and an else statement... i cant understand why. The code makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your `var` statements at the top of the function/script.  `var` declares the variable, and you only need to do that once.

e.g.

```
var name, PromptAnswer, PromptAnswer2, PromptAnswer3;
...
name = ...;
```